# Reduce number of fonts used (from default settings)

Tags: fonts

Why does the default LaTeX setting of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` use so many different fonts (e.g. `\mathrm{}` uses a different font than `\textrm{}`)? At least the Adobe Acrobat Reader shows me a list that contains:

- CMBX10,
- CMEX10,
- CMMI...,
- CMR...,
- CMSY...,
- F108,
- F109,
- SFBX...,
- SFRM...,
- SFSL1000,
- SFTT1000

Can I reduce the number of fonts used in a document? Why are there so many fonts (even of the same family)?

Comment: The first group (CM...) derives from math formulas in which you apparently used also `\mathrm` and `\mathbf`. The F... group can mean anything, so you should be more precise. The SF... group is for the text fonts. What's the problem?

Comment: @egreg: I thought it would be reasonable to reduce the number of fonts involved in the document - as using same font for `\textrm` and `\mathrm` etc.

Comment: I still can't see how to answer this question. There are *no* fonts from the same family, as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, but *you* are saying that and you should explain what you mean. Apparently our notion of “same family” are different.

Comment: The F... group is added by the package `bbm` which provides the command `\mathbbm{1}`. I understand that this font can not be neglected if I want to use this command. About your last comment: I am using in a file the font `CMBX10` with encoding `built-in` and once with encoding `custom`. Do you have an explanation for that? (This is what I mean by "same family".)

Comment: That means it is subsetting fonts rather than including the entire font. This tends to keep documents smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
Some math:
\[\int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = 1 \]

\end{document}
```

has 6 fonts, always embedded as a subset. The file is 39kB big.

With an uncommented `\usepackage{kpfonts}` it has 4 fonts embedded and the file is 26 kB.

Comment: So am I right that `kpfonts` sets the font of the math environment and the ones of the standard text to kpfonts? I did not wanted to change my fonts but I thought to use the same font in default and math mode.

Comment: @strpeter - If the `kpfonts` package is loaded, there will still be different fonts in use for the text-upright and math-upright portions, and for the text-italic and math-italic portions, of the document. Of course, a symbol font (for the integral symbol and the fraction bar) will also be needed.

Comment: @Mico: As I wrote, with kpfonts you'll have four fonts embedded: one text and three math fonts.

Comment: @Herbert - I know that's what you wrote. :-) I was mainly trying to address the OP's follow-up question, which seemed to indicate some uncertainty as to whether the `kpfonts` package uses the *same font* for text and math; it does not.