# Fixing mathit spacing with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, opentype, lhs2tex

I am using lhs2TeX to convert code into LaTeX. It typesets code into math mode. As I am also writing math formulas in the same document, I use unicode-math to switch between different math mode fonts in order to make the two things more distinct (and also to use Unicode symbols in my math).

lhs2TeX sets variable identifiers using a macro `\Varid`, which is usually set to `\mathit`.

The problem here is that with unicode-math, `\mathit` does not work correctly. I am unsure whether this is a problem with unicode-math or the OpenType math fonts, but the bottom line is that it does not typeset its argument as text but like a formula, with additional spacing between the letters. I also found a [bug report on this](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/254).

I could redefine `\Varid` with `\textit`, but this leads to another problem: There are a lot of subscripts in my identifiers, and as the underscore doesn't do subscripts in text mode, this doesn't work. At least not without me overriding every identifier with custom TeX to fix the subscripts.

Here is an example demonstrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=lm]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=pg]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\begin{document}

\mathversion{lm}
% math in latin modern
    $x ∼ y$

\mathversion{pg}
% haskell code in tex gyre pagella

    \textit{factorial}

    $\mathit{factorial}$ \quad This should look like the former, not the latter.

    $factorial$

\mathversion{lm}
% latin modern again
    $x ∼ y$

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Output]
<sub>(source: [goedderz.info](http://tobias.goedderz.info/perm/um-mathit.png))</sub>

So the question is: Can mathit be fixed in this setting? If not, can I write a macro that works in math mode, but chooses the correct font? Or can I write a macro which locally redefines the underscore to do subscripts in text mode?

**Edit:** A main problem here, that unfortunately isn't part of my example, is that the TeX code inside `\Varid` (which can be redefined) is usually automatically generated and often contains `_` for subscripts (or else must be rewritten manually for every identifier which I try to avoid). So using `\text` instead is problematic.

**Edit:** Actually, that is not quite true, as something like `x1` gets translated to `\Varid{x}_1`, which works when defining `\Varid` as something like

```
\newfontfamily\haskvarfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\renewcommand{\Varid}[1]{\text{\haskvarfont\emph{#1}}}
```

Comment: They look correct to me; You should use `\textit` for function names and such. For super-/subscript, just use, for example, `\textit{factorial}_{\textit{foo}}`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178791/differences-of-fonts-in-math-and-text-mode) for why `\mathit` works the way it does. Oh, and welcome to tex.stackexchange!

Comment: @morbusg No! This is a bug in unicode-math that really should be fixed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the consequence of a bad decision in `unicode-math`: they named `\mathit` the normal math italic letters, instead of respecting the LaTeX convention of referring to them as `\mathnormal`; `\mathit` should choose the text italic font, in order to make `unicode-math` a drop-in replacement.

I wouldn't expect different output when `unicode-math` is loaded or not; but this simple example shows the bug:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\mathit{different}$

$different$

\end{document}
```

If the line with `unicode-math` is commented out, we get

[image]

If I uncomment the line, I get

[image]

which is ***definitely*** wrong.

### Workaround:

Define a new math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\Lmathit}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$\Lmathit{different}$

$different$

\end{document}
```

If you use `lhs2TeX`, you can add

```
\renewcommand{\Conid}[1]{\Lmathit{#1}}
\renewcommand{\Varid}[1]{\Lmathit{#1}}
```

after loading it.

This shouldn't raise the `Too many math alphabets` error; if it does, then add the code you find between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100428/4427

Comment: Something along those lines was my first workaround as well: I **can** redefine `\Varid`. However, the TeX code inside is automatically generated and often contains _ for subscripts. Using `\text` breaks this.

Comment: @TobiasGödderz If I say `$x_\Varid{ff}$` I get the expected result. I added a pair of braces for safety.

Comment: But `$\Lmathit{x_1}$` doesn't.

Comment: @TobiasGödderz `\mathit{x_1}` is wrong to begin with; it should be `\mathit{x}_1`

Comment: Ah, you're right. And actually, lhs2TeX does generate code that way -- it was an identifier I formatted myself that prevented your example from working.

Comment: @TobiasGödderz I've changed the workaround to a better one.

Comment: Naming “mathematical italic” `\mathit` doesn’t sound like a bug to me. If something else uses “mathematical italic” to mean “text italic”, then the bug is IMHO in that.

Comment: @morbusg The problem is not in the name, but in the fact that, for LaTeX, `\mathit` means using the *text italic* font (as opposed to the normal math italic). Maybe the name was badly chosen twenty years ago; too late for changing the convention.

Comment: Welp, if it were too late for changing conventions in general, we’d still be watching the sun revolve around our flat Earth… Calling it a bug in `unicode-math` just feels very wrong to me.

Comment: @egreg I wouldn't say that `\mathit{x_1}` is intrinsically wrong. Indeed `fontmath.ltx` contains `\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{\`1}` etc, hence one can do `\mathbf{1_2}` if one wishes to. No guarantee of course this gives the same bold `1` as `\boldsymbol {1}`.

Comment: @morbusg what is wrong, but explained by the historical constraints, is that `TeX` only envisions italic fonts for math letters, hence `LaTeX` does provide `\mathnormal` where there should be a `\mathnormalit` and also `\mathnormalrm` and perhaps a `\mathnormalother` which would give upright letters if the user respects the default italic setup, and italic letters if the user has done something like `\mathupright`.

Comment: @morbusg -- while the name `\mathit` is a latex introduction,  "math italic" is knuthian terminology; the plain tex command is `\mit`, and the concept is introduced on p.164 of the *texbook*.  the terminology may be confusing, but some things *won't* change as long as you're using tex of any flavor.

Comment: @barbara: Confusing? No; I know `\mit` does `\fam1` on plain, and I even linked on the OP to the question which deals with the differences between the two italics.

Comment: @jfbu In the olden times one had to say `${\it func}(x)$`, which LaTeX2e removed preferring `$\mathit{func}(x)$`. However the name shouldn't be read “math italic”, but “italics used in math”. With LaTeX2e, the declaration `\mit`  (taken from Plain TeX), became the command with an argument `\mathnormal`.

Comment: @morbusg -- i've now gone back and read the linked item on github.  in that, will robertson has asked if `\mit` should be used for the new unicode material.  i've written to will suggesting *very* strongly that this is a bad idea, and cited the *texbook* reference.  one could wish the terminology were different, but it's not; egreg's phrasing -- "italics used in math" -- is probably the best/easiest way to remember the concept "correctly" (i.e., as it is used in tex).

Comment: After reading the github conversation, I am starting to question my own sanity. Just wanted to throw that out there. `;-D`

Comment: @egreg: Your workaround doesn't work with TeXLive 2014 and LuaLaTeX. Could you update your solution?

Comment: @Maggyero There's no update, unfortunately. The upgrade from TL2013 to 2014 broke everything. :(

Comment: @egreg: That's a serious issue. Did Will Robertson correct this for TeXLive 2015 in his `unicode-math` package? (It's about to be frozen so I hope so.)

Comment: @Maggyero No, it does the same in TL2015/pretest

Comment: @egreg: Is he aware of the problem?

Comment: @Maggyero Yes, he is.

Comment: @morbusg Whether the earth is flat could not be a matter of convention. We might have a convention of saying so or thinking so, but we couldn't have one of its being so.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$\mathit{different}$

$\symit{different}$

$different$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation?