# using rightarrows and bullets

Tags: itemize, bullets

I wanted to use bullets and rightarrows in pdf document, unfortunately i am running in to some error "Missing } inserted". and not able to indentify the error. Can anyone suggest below is the example i have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
$\bullet$ \; \item \textsf{a \leq b }
\newline 
$\rightarrow$ \textbf{text } \\
$\bullet$ \; \item \textbf{b \geq c }
\newline
$\rightarrow$ \textbf{text }\\
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `\\` or `\newline` in an itemized list. The `itemize` environment should have the following syntax:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Contents of first item
\item Contents of second item
\end{itemize}
```

The items will be marked with bullets by default. For example, the code

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $a \leq b$
\item $b \geq c$
\end{itemize}
```

will produce the following:

[image]

If you want to change the symbol to an arrow, you can use `\item[\rightarrow]`

[image]

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $a \leq b$
\item[$\rightarrow$] \textbf{text}
\item $b \geq c$
\item[$\rightarrow$] \textbf{text}
\end{itemize}
```

Itemized lists can be nested. They will be indented automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $a \leq b$
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[$\rightarrow$] \textbf{text}
  \end{itemize}
\item $b \geq c$
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[$\rightarrow$] \textbf{text}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh ok thanks, but the fonts always changes with in the item. How can we maintain the same font from the beginning to end of the document ?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about the difference between math mode and text mode? LaTeX intentionally typesets these differently. [See here] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178791/125871) for more information. In your example you used `\textbf`, which makes the (text) characters bold. Perhaps you should post another question with an example where the font changes unexpectedly.

Comment: It works with textbf. Thanks